# How to post/create database rows [sql server] into Salesforce API

Tags: webservices, c#

How to post database rows into Salesforce API and create records. I've all the login credentials i.e. access token & client ID and I want to create/post sql server database rows into SalesForce API through C#. Anyone kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

you need to load data from sql database, transform it to json format and load to salesforce. You can use [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm)

```
curl https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/
 -H "Authorization: Bearer token -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@newaccount.json"
```

Example request

```
{
  "Name" : "Express Logistics and Transport"
}
```

example response

```
{
  "id" : "001D000000IqhSLIAZ",
  "errors" : [ ],
  "success" : true
}
```

also  you can use [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_create.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working from .NET with the Salesforce APIs you might find the [Salesforce Toolkits for .NET](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/01/announcing-the-salesforce-toolkits-for-net.html) to be a good starting point. They will handle most of the REST API calls for you.

You mention moving SQL Server data directly in Salesforce. You might also consider a third party tool like [DBAmp](http://www.forceamp.com/) that allows Salesforce to appear as a linked server in the database. Having your own C# code do the integration will give you more flexibility, but something like DBAmp could speed up a simple integration.